# How can I require that at least two lookahead patterns match within one regex?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

The following regex ensures a password contains at least one lowercase, one uppercase, one number, and one special character:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]).*$
```

That works. Building on this, I'd like to require that only two of these groups be fulfilled in order for a password to be valid.

For example, these would be valid passwords: aaaaa5, BFEWREWRE77, #2ccc.

Is there I way I can modify this regex to support this requirement?

Comment: This is not a job for regular expressions. Better try to run through the string and count how many characters of each kind it contains. Next check the counts against your rules. It is also more clear for the next person that will read the code.

Comment: Sure, it might be better suited with code. But I want to do it with a regex. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

with spaces forbidden:

```
^(?=([A-Z]+|[a-z]+|[0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+))\1\S+$
```

with spaces allowed:

```
^\s*(?=((?:[A-Z]+\s*)+|(?:[a-z]+\s*)+|(?:[0-9]+\s*)+|(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\s*)+))\1.+$
```

explanations:

`(?=([A-Z]+|[a-z]+|[0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+))\1` emulates the [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `(?>[A-Z]+|[a-z]+|[0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)`. So once a branch of this group is matched, the regex engine is no more allowed to backtrack inside the matched characters.

Since the quantifiers are greedy by default, all the characters of one of the categories are matched by the atomic group.

The next character matched by `\S` or `.` is obviously from a different character class than the one used in the group.

Note: for the second pattern, since there is no limitation about the characters used in the string, you don't need to test the string until the end, so you can write:

```
^\s*(?=((?:[A-Z]+\s*)+|(?:[a-z]+\s*)+|(?:[0-9]+\s*)+|(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\s*)+))\1.
```

Comment: very smart, hats off +1

Comment: DING DING DING DING DING! We have a winner. It's nice and short too. Knew it could be done. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ChadJohnson: are spaces allowed?

Comment: Nope -- thanks for asking. Hey one more question: If you wanted to require not just two but three characters, how would you enforce three?

Comment: @ChadJohnson: I don't think you can extend this technic to three character classes.

Comment: @ChadJohnson: to do the same for three character classes (following the same idea), you obtain this: http://regex101.com/r/pK9xM4/1 it's relativly efficient but a bit long. In this case the simple way is to test each character classes in four different pattern and to count the number of success.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for this long regex:

```
^(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])|(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])).+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iX8bF2/1)

Comment: Haha...nice. This certainly works, though I think I'll go with Casimir et Hippolyte's version because it's shorter :)

Answer (score 1):

Most modern engines offer conditionals.
This is a simple example pattern that inhibits re-entering the same group
and guarantees X out of Y requirements.

In essence, the groups are matched in no particular order based on *only*
the quantifier number *X*, which is the criteria that causes an alignment.

Its very scalable, just add a new group in the alternation.
Set *X* for how many unique groups you want to match.

This one is set for 3 out of the 4.
And just finish it off with any boundary requirements you have,  like
`^`+regex_below+`.*$`.

Also, this consumes as it goes. It could easily be within a lookahead should there
be any length or other specific attributes.

Note that if the engine doesn't support conditionals (not all do), then this won't work.

```
 #  (?:.*?(?>((?(1)(?!))[a-z]+)|((?(2)(?!))[A-Z]+)|((?(3)(?!))[0-9]+)|((?(4)(?!))[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+))){3}

 (?:
      .*?     
      (?>
           (                        # (1)
                (?(1) (?!) )
                [a-z]+ 
           )
        |  (                        # (2)
                (?(2) (?!) )
                [A-Z]+ 
           )
        |  (                        # (3)
                (?(3) (?!) )
                [0-9]+ 
           )
        |  (                        # (4)
                (?(4) (?!) )
                [^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+ 
           )
      )
 ){3}
```

Sample output when *X* is 4 (out of 4)

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 11 ) 
B,B_+&*%#a0  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 9 , len 1 ) 
a  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 0 , len 1 ) 
B  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 10 , len 1 ) 
0  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 1 , len 1 ) 
,
```

Comment: I think my head exploded.

Comment: @ChadJohnson - Hope the explosion wasn't fatal. I left this regex for advanced use. Its not really meant to be understood by anyone - maybe a few.

Comment: Haha, only joking man. This is good stuff...thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @ChadJohnson - Did a lot of debug testing of this construct. Found that adding the atomic group around the alternations fixed a bunch of latency-backtracking. And, found that performance wise its just as fast as a ton of lookaheads from an anchor postion (ie. `^`). This means two paradigm's turn into one. Less than or equal to. Hinges on conditionals though. This particular conditional can be simulated in Dot-Net fwiw. Happy New Year!!

Answer (score 0):

you would have to do something like :

```
^(
    (?=1)(?=2)
    |
    (?=1)(?=3)
    |
    (?=1)(?=4)
    |
    (?=2)(?=3)
    |
    (?=2)(?=4)
    |
    (?=3)(?=4)
).*$
```

where 1,2,3 & 4 are your different patterns