# RegEx: Non-repeating patterns?

Tags: regex, string, nsregularexpression

I'm wrestling with how to write a specific regex, and thought I'd come here for a little guidance.

What I'm looking for is an expression that does the following:

- Character length of 7 or more
- Any single character is one of four patterns (uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers and a specific set of special characters. Let's say **#$%@**).

(Now, here's where I'm having problems):

- Another single character would also match with one of the patterns described above EXCEPT for the pattern that was already matched. So, if the first pattern matched is an uppercase letter, the second character match should be a lowercase letter, number or special character from the pattern.

To give you an example, the string **AAAAAA#** would match, as would the string **AAAAAAa**. However, the string **AAAAAAA**, nor would the string **AAAAAA&** (as the ampersand was not part of the special character pattern).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In other words, you're looking for 7 or more characters that include characters from at least two of the four groups?

Comment: Use lookarounds, its pretty easy.

Comment: Would AaAAAAa match?

Comment: @brunch875 - Yes, it would. A & a would fill the requirement of matches from two of the four pattern groups.

Comment: Side note: Why does it have to be a regex? Because this seems like a password regex.

Comment: Should it match *exactly* 2 out of 4 patterns? or it has to match 2+ patterns? Is "`A%Bc5Ef`" valid?

Comment: @Mariano 2+ is fine.

Comment: I have to comment because I got 2 downvotes on an answer based upon your question. I took a guess but, apparently some people can read minds. You focus on capital letters only in your examples. The real danger is SO gets flooded with duplicate questions. This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110036/how-can-i-require-that-at-least-two-lookahead-patterns-match-within-one-regex/27112936#27112936 . My answer is then ..

Answer (score 2):

If you only need two different kinds of characters, you can use the possessive quantifier feature (available in Objective C):

```
^(?:[a-z]++|[A-Z]++|[0-9]++|[#$%@]++)[a-zA-Z0-9#$%@]+$
```

or more concise with an atomic group:

```
^(?>[a-z]+|[A-Z]+|[0-9]+|[#$%@]+)[a-zA-Z0-9#$%@]+$
```

Since each branch of the alternation is a character class with a possessive quantifier, you can be sure that the first character matched by `[a-zA-Z0-9#$%@]+` is from a different class.

About the string size, check it first separately with the appropriate function, if the size is too small, you will avoid the cost of a regex check.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to do a negative lookahead to make sure the entire string doesn't consist of characters from a single group:

```
(?!(?:[a-z]*|[A-Z]*|[0-9]*|[#$%@]*)$)
```

Then check that it *does* contain at least 7 characters from the list of legal characters (and nothing else):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9#$%@]{7,}$
```

Combining them (thanks to [Shlomo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415661/shlomo) for pointing that out):

```
^(?!(?:[a-z]*|[A-Z]*|[0-9]*|[#$%@]*)$)[a-zA-Z0-9#$%@]{7,}$
```

Comment: You can combine these two into one regex: `^(?!^(?:[a-z]*|[A-Z]*|[0-9]*|[#$%@]*)$)[a-zA-Z0-9#$%@]{7,}$`

Comment: @Shlomo Heh... quite right. Editing that in. Thanks!